# How to perform only unit tests for Bot and Xcode Server?

Tags: xcode, unit-testing, xcode-server

So far I execute unit and ui tests with Xcode Server's Bot. Is it possible to run **ONLY** unit tests?

This is configuration for my Bot:

[image]

I have a separated schemes for Unit and UITests but it doesn't work when I run bot. Error is following:

> Assertion: No destinations were specified with the -destination flag which were valid for the specified scheme 'MySoberRoomMateTests'.

Answer (score 0):

If your project contains both Unit Tests and UI Tests, by default Xcode Server will run both test suites during an integration. To change this behavior you will need to deselect the UI Tests in the shared schemes test settings.

[image: Shared Scheme Test Settings]

You can get to this screen in Xcode by going to Product > Scheme > Edit Scheme.

You shouldn't create additional schemes just for testing. Testing needs to be associated with an application target.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a new argument to xcodebuild in the Arguments tab of the bot configuration:

`-only-testing:YOUR_TEST_TARGET`